# Should I comment my tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, comments

I am about to write just another Java-Test which covers a new feature. To document the reason for this new tests I am thinking about commenting the test with an explanation of the feature.

Should I do that?

What is a good way to link the tests with the features?

Comment: one would hope that any test would be self-explanatory...except perhaps for //Arrange, //Act, //Assert

Comment: Usually project documentation contains matrix with mapping between use cases and test cases

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2198458/307767

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should name your tests in such a way that it's obvious which feature is under test, and the conditions of that test.

If, for some reason, that is not possible, then and only then should you add minimal commentary to your test; as should be the case for ANY code you write.

Answer (score 1):

Usually what we do is come up with descriptive test names, so that in case of test failures we can pin point which feature failed, without looking through the test code.

eg : `divideWithZeroShouldFailAndThrowAnException()` is a perfect test method name if you are plannign to test a `Calculator` class's `divide` method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, code of your test should be self-explanatory. In addition to GaryF's answer I suggest to use assert methods that take a message describing a reason what's wrong in cases when it's not so clear. For example, [assertEquals(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

It helps you understand what exactly was broken even if you look at test results, not in test code.